# Error : The command '/bin/sh returned a non-zero code: 1

Tags: mysql, docker

When I am trying to build one of my projects by running a script written by  previous team in my ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo ./build
```

I am getting error :

```
Step 8/24 : RUN     service mysql start
 ---> Running in 3djjk653642d
 * Starting MySQL database server mysqld
 ...fail!
The command '/bin/sh -c service mysql start' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

My Dockerfile looks like:

```
COPY        schema.sql /tmp/schema.sql
### User with ALL accesses (winter/toor)
RUN     service mysql start
RUN     mysql < /tmp/schema.sql
RUN     mysql -e "CREATE USER 'winter'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'toor'"
RUN     service mysql start && mysql -e "GRANT ALL ON its.* TO 'winter'@'%'"
```

Please ,any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RUN` statements in a Dockerfile are used to run a command which will have some effect on the filesystem, that is then saved in another layer.

It's not normal to start a service like this, as the state of the memory (where the service is running) is not stored in the image, it can only be running in a running container.

The normal way to do stuff like this would be to write a bash script, (called `start.sh`, or something similar), copy it into the image and then run from an `ENTRYPOINT` / `CMD` line at the end of the Dockerfile. This will be run when the container is created in a `docker run ...` command

**start.sh:**

```
service mysql start
mysql < /tmp/schema.sql
mysql -e "CREATE USER 'winter'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'toor'"
service mysql start && mysql -e "GRANT ALL ON its.* TO 'winter'@'%'"
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
COPY        schema.sql /tmp/schema.sql
COPY        start.sh /
ENTRYPOINT  ["/start.sh"]
```

Have a read [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) for some information on the difference between `ENTRYPOINT` & `CMD` and when each should be used.

Better still - use the official MySQL image from [Docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/). Through the use of environment variables, you could probably achieve all you require.

Answer (score 0):

For me the error was:

```
yum -y install nginx' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

This docker file helped me:

```
FROM centos:7

MAINTAINER linuxtechlab

LABEL Remarks="This is a dockerfile example for Centos system"

RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install httpd
RUN yum clean all
RUN yum -y install nginx

EXPOSE 80

#ENV HOME /root
#WORKDIR /root
#ENTRYPOINT ["ping"]
#CMD ["google.com"]
```